KafkaProducer Optimization
I am currently pushing 14.5 million records to a Kafka producer using java KafkaProducer API (broker version & kafka-client version is 3.6.1), but the process is taking approximately 2 hours 10 minutes to complete.
Could you please assist me in optimizing the Kafka producer configurations to reduce the processing time? .
My configurations:
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 100000);
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 50);
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
props.put("buffer.memory", 67108864);
props.put("retries", 3);
props.put("retry.backoff.ms", 5000);
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5");
props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "10000");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);  

How to check the producer metrics for this.Any changes required to these configurations.please suggest.


What research have you done to get the metrics (this is already well documented, so what is your question about metrics asking for?) 2) Show a [mcve]. This code alone doesn't cause a slowdown 3) Why would you use only one producer to push millions of messages?


@OneCricketeer can u suggest on how to use multiple producers to push millions to messages..my application is running on 4 machines....In each machine also can i use multiple producers to push msg into topic..Could you please suggest on this to how to do.

Yes. Learn Java threads or run your app more than once, each with a subset of data, or use the console producer as I said
